# React-Router using a loading page while fetching a DB

Tags: api, redirect, reactjs, react-router

So, I finished my app using React Router and everything works as expected. When the user enters the page, he gets redirected to a loading screen while my `App` component fetches a DB, and after the fetch is done the user gets redirected to the category that was fetched.

`/` -> `<Loader />` -> `/App().state.data[0].category`.

The fetch is done so fast that the user cannot even see the loading screen, as expected. So the user experiences.

`/` -> `/App().state.data[0].category`.

**So my problem is** that when the user is on the `/App().state.data[0].category` page, and he hits the back button, he will see and stay on the loading screen. So he basically has to double click to go back to the previous page. This is not desired.

What the user experiences

`/App().state.data[0].category` -> `<Loader />` ->  `Page before entering the "/"`

What the user **should** experience

`/App().state.data[0].category` ->  `Page before entering the "/"`

**My Question** is there a way to jump the loading screen if the user presses the back button?

I started looking into the `history` npm thing, am I on the right track?

My current config looks like this in pseudocode:

*main.js*

```
render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
   <Route path="/" component={App}>
    /* This returns the first category from my api  */
    <IndexRedirect to={App().state.data[0].category} />
    <Route path=":category" component={App} />
   </Route>
  </Router>
,document.getElementById('main'));
```

*App.js*

```
class App extends React.Component{
  componentWillMount() {
    const router = this.context.router;
    fetchData().then(function(results){
      router.push(results.data[0].category);
    })
 }

  render() {
    return (<Loader/>);
 }
}
```

Comment: If you really want to give a loader a URL history record, you can try `window.history.go(-1-numOfLoaders);` for back button and increase the `numOfLoaders` when you add a loader. For example, if you have 1 loader page, you will get `window.history.go(-2)`.

But in the cases what I had done, I hadn't set a loader page a URL history record.

Comment: And if you really take my way, you need to do some error handlings for `window.history.length`.

Comment: @AndreLee I posted this in another forum and a guy told me to replace `router.push` by `router.replace`. Do you think that that will fix the problem? I will give your solution also a try. **EDIT:** And when I said the back button, I meant the one on the web browser

Comment: Yes, `router.replace()` should be the one which is better than my solution. I forgot it suddenly.

Answer (score 0):

why not do a conditional render on a single component.

if database -> render the page

else -> render the loader

as soon as your db fetch is complete, the render will mount and you will see your page instead of your loader